# How to Multiple Multilines input on python

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, multiline, sys, eoferror

When I try to use multiple multilines input, the second multiline input interpret the ctrl + d as his and does not wait for my new input. Even if I try to use another simple input it does not work. I tried with the loop and with the sys readlines() but it does not work. I think the issue is with the EOFError used to finish the first multiline.

Here is my code:

```
import sys

print("Please paste a multiline code and press ctrl + d")
userInput1 = sys.stdin.readlines()
print(userInput1)

print("Please paste a multiline code and press ctrl + d")
userInput2 = sys.stdin.readlines()
print(userInput2)

userInput3 = input("Input something")
print(userInput3)
```

I even did with a loop but the result is the same:

```
def getl():
    try:
        x = input()
    except EOFError:
        return ""
    return x

def getline():
    text = []
    line = self.getl()
    while line != "":
        text.append(line)
        line = self.getl()
    print(text)

print("Please paste a multiline code and press ctrl + d")
input1 = getline()
print(input1)

print("Please paste a multiline code and press ctrl + d")
input2 = getline()
print(input2)
```

I even tried with another while loop! LOL

```
def input_lines_to_list(text, list):
    list = list
    print(text)
    have_lines = True
    while have_lines:
        try:
            line = input()
        except EOFError:
            break
        list.append(line)
        if line == "":
            have_lines = False
    return list

text = "Please paste a multiline code and press ctrl + d"
lines_list1 = []
lines_list1 = input_lines_to_list(text, lines_list1)

lines_list2 = []
lines_list2 = input_lines_to_list(text, lines_list2)
```

If I use this input_lines_to_list() two times it does not work too... Even If I use it first and then a simple input it does not work.

Anyone knows a way around? Thanks!

PS: All of these methods work well if I use it for only one input use.

Comment: how do you run it? What do you send to this script?

Comment: why do you use `Ctrl+D`? Maybe problem is not your code but how system threads `Ctrl+D` - system may finish your script when it see Ctrl+D.

Comment: The script works well if I use just use it once. It get all the multilines input and make a list. The problem is that I need to use Ctrl + D to make it get all the lines, and with that I can't use another input afterwards....

Comment: @furas Just copy my code and run it, you will be able to ctrl + v a multiline text and then you need to press  ctrl+d you will see that it will print the list with all the lines. But it will not work a second time!

Comment: @furas If I dont use ctrl+D the input keeps waiting for me to insert more lines.

Comment: Your very first code segments works exactly as you wanted for me, [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNUpO.png)

Comment: @metatoaster that's weird, for me it get's an error [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/FAxKrjm.png)

Comment: Looks like an OS or terminal related issue. I am not using Windows.

Comment: @metatoaster Thank you, I will have a look. I'm using pycharm on windows.

Comment: as I know `PyCharm` may simulate terminal instead of use real terminal - and it may work different.

Comment: THe problem is indeed pycharm. On powershell runs smoothly, thank you guys!